# What are the best practices to use Firebase notification in Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on Firebase push notification for my Flutter Application. I am working on it first time so not aware much about it.

I wanted to know what are best practices using Firebase Push Notification.

I have implemented Notification code at Android side and tried to send notification from console. It is receiving on Mobile app if application is in background and foreground state.

We are setting up server which will store the FCM token at server side database and send the push notification whenever the event triggered.
Is this the correct way I am doing or I need to make changes if any required?

Also I want solution for one use case.
How do I fetch all notifications from firebase? Should I store all sending notifications to the server database? What will be better solution in this use case?

Comment: You can refer to this video, I've also learned from it 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUU6gbDni4Q&ab_channel=dbestech